# Installing and running two versions of mod_wsgi in Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to setup Python3 and Python2 via mod_wsgi on Ubuntu, so I've installed the mod_wsgi_py3 package but also wish to run the py2 version and have it switched depending on a flag within the virtualhosts config. Is there any way to do this withing Apache 2.2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible. you would need to run two Apache instances, each with different mod_wsgi binary compiled for the Python version you want to use.

Comment: That is disappointing. I was considering modifying the mod_wsgi binary for py2 to prefix all directives with PY2_ in order to have them both loaded side-by-side. I assume that will work but that's also not really road I'm ready to embark on.

Comment: It is much deeper than just changing directive names. For a start you can't load the two different Python shared libraries for different Python versions into memory at the same time.